# Corona; How do I create a database so that users can access it online using their android phones?

Tags: android, sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to make an game using corona sdk where a user can see what items he has and how much he has left. Its abit like a inventory management app. How do i go about doing this? I have no idea what to do and where to start. Currently what I found online is this:

```
-- open "data.db". If the file doesn't exist, it will be created
local path = system.pathForFile( "data.db", system.DocumentsDirectory )
local db = sqlite3.open( path )
```

This actually creates a local database which I don't want. I'm guessing instead of "system.DocumentsDirectory" I should put in something else? I referred online at corona labs (http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/04/03/tutorial-database-access-in-corona/) but nothing really gave me what I needed.

Any help on this is welcomed. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I'm using SQLite if that's important. Also if anyone is not sure what I'm trying to ask, basically I'm trying to have a database stored online so that i can access it using my android device. How do i do that and what tools do I need?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a REST API to manage online database and then use the HTTP requests to create, remove, update or delete records.
I would suggest to work on HTTP server which would provide you endpoints to interact with your database records then use Corona's network requests to communicate with the server. You can use the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format to easily exchange data over HTTP.

You can read more about network requests [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html).
If you want to know about REST APIs or database endpoints you can start reading about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).
You can read about using JSON in Corona SDK [here](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/08/03/tutorial-exploring-json-usage-in-corona/).